# The value of a range that is variable

Tags: vba, range, cell

I have a code which loops to the Sheet("Overview") if the value of Cells(Y,X) is equal to  " " then Y = Y + 1 otherwise the rest. The code runs fault on the part

```
If Range(Cells(Y,X).Address).Value = "" Then
```

If I put for instance "H4" in it works but not like this. What am I doing wrong with the Cells refence?

The whole code for the loop is:

```
Sub Maandag1()

Dim X As String
Dim Y As String
    X = 8
    Y = 4

    
    Do While Y <= 4
        
        If Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(Y, X).Address).Value = " " Then
            Y = Y + 1
        Else
            With Sheets("Controle")
                .Range("B7").Value = Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(Y, X).Address).Value
                .Range("B8").Value = Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(Y, X + 1).Address).Value
                .Range("B13").Value = Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(Y, X + 2).Address).Value
                .Range("B18").Value = Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(Y, X + 3).Address).Value
                .Range("B23").Value = Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(Y, X + 4).Address).Value
                .Range("B28").Value = Sheets("Overview").Range(Cells(Y, X + 5).Address).Value
            End With
            
            Y = Y + 1
        End If
    Loop
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that line of code to:

`If Sheets("Overview").Cells(Y, X).Value = " " Then`

No need to create the Range object with the `.Cells` method only to use that range to get the string address to use as a way to again build the range.

But the real problem here is that you've declared `X` and `Y` as strings. The `.Cells` operation wants to take long params

```
Dim X as Long
Dim Y as Long
```